# SQL dynamic sub-queries

Tags: sql-server, dynamic, subquery

I am running SQL Server 2016 Management Studio. Currently I have the following sub-query structure

```
WITH x_1 AS
    (SELECT
        -- Code A here --
        column_1       
        -- Code B here -- 
    ),
x_2 AS
    (SELECT
        -- Code A here --
        column_2       
        -- Code B here -- 
    )
SELECT
-- Rest of the code --
```

So essentially I am performing the same code snippets for both sub-queries ("Code A" and "Code B") except for the reference to a different column in between. In order avoid unnecessary repetition, in other programming languages I could e.g. do something along the lines of the following pseudocode snippet

```
varnames = ["x_1", "x_2"]
colnames = ["col_1", "col_2"]

for (i in 1:2){
   eval(varnames[i]) = function(name = colnames[i]){Code A, eval(name), Code B}  
}
```

That is, loop over the code blocks twice and dynamically evaluate the variable and column names. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this in SQL. Any ideas how it could be achieved? Does this approach make sense in SQL or are there some more suitable ways to achieve the same result?

Comment: Sounds like something you could do in a stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

A looping approach does not make sense in SQL, since set-based approaches invariably perform better.

Without knowing what "Code A" and "Code B" actually are, it's hard to suggest an ideal solution with 100% confidence.   However, taking your word that they are identical except for the one column, I would suggest combining the two CTE's into one CTE that either has both columns in it, or if the two columns share the same alias, uses CASE expression to use `column_1` when appropriate for the extra column, and `column_2` otherwise.